# Upload UDF in BigQuery using Python API Client

Tags: google-bigquery, user-defined-functions, google-api-python-client

I would like to create a UDF inside a specific dataset in BigQuery. I've tried using the create_table and other API methods from the **Python Client** but none seem to work.

Is there any method or way to upload a UDF (stored in a file and read it as a string) into BigQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my UDF:

```
$ cat test.udf
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dataset_name.addFourAndDivideAny(x ANY TYPE, y ANY TYPE) AS ((x + 4) / y);
```

This is my upload command ran on Cloud Shell (it will ask to authorise):

```
bq query --nouse_legacy_sql  < test.udf
```

In python:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

with open('test.udf', 'r') as file:
     QUERY = file.read().replace('\n', '')

query_job = client.query(QUERY)
```

*I have got the UDF in single line in the file, but you can use multi-lines file as well. Just make sure the QUERY string is properly constructed.*

Comment: This works perfectly using the bq in bash.

But I was wondering if this could also be achieved in Python?

Comment: @Julian - I have added python way as well.

Comment: Ye, i did the same way, I was creating a job_config and calling methods: create_table and some others instead of just querying what I was needing. Thanks so much :)